# What is good size ratio for a 2D tile-based game's chunks ? [Screen Ratio or 1:1 Ratio ?]

Tags: actionscript-3, 2d, tile

I am making a 2D tile based game and I expect to have a really big world. 
As I want movement between areas to be seamless I will obviously need to load the world in chunks.
So the question is :

- Is it better if my chunk's size is based on my game's resolution
- Is it better if my chunk's size is a perfect square

---

Let's have an example with simple numbers ;
If my game's resolution is 1024x768 and my tiles are 32x32,
I can fit 32x24 tiles in one screen.

Let's say I'd like my chunks a bit bigger than the screen,

- Is it better to have a 128x128 tiles chunk
- Is it better to have a 128x96 tiles chunk

---

As far as I know my question is irrelevant and either would do but I'm afraid I might end up facing an unexpected error if I choose the wrong one.

Comment: If I were making such a game, my instinct would tell me I should design my code to keep it flexible or easy to change later. Either that or spend a bit more time on the design and just try out multiple sizes. Most likely you'd end up iterating and there will be things you suddenly decide to change later on as you go.

Answer (score 1):

I think either direction you decide to take with handling chunk size, it is definitely going to be a wise decision to leave it abstracted enough to allow for some flexibility in size (if not for your own unit tests).

That being said, this is a question of performance really and doing textures/assets in powers of 2 was a good restriction back before dedicated GPU's were around. I'm not really sure if you'll see a huge difference between the two nowadays (although you might with it being flash) but it's usually a safe route to keep the tiles as a power of 2. In the past when working with rendering, keeping assets to a power of 2 meant it would always divide evenly and that saves on some computations.

Hope this helps! :)